# Making points transparents

Tags: matlab, colors, plot

I have a plot similar to the one below. This is a cylindar. The points near the axis are red and become more and more blue when they get far from it.

The problem is that the blue points completely hide the red ones. 
Is there any way to make these blue points transparent enough to see what's inside?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I could suggest a hack to try. Given that you approximately know what the colors of the points you want to remove are, you could use findall or findobj to extract the line objects from your plots (maybe they're named something else in a 3D plot, don't have a lot of experience there) and then just delete those with the blue coloration.